# How to change the content (text) when the user fiddles with an html range slider?

Tags: java, html, css

I'm totally new to JS. I want to change the content in the article once the user slides an html slider. How do I proceed?

I wanted to do some thing like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6al3.jpg.

```
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="scan">
            <h3>SCAN</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderr">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="1" class="slider" id="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="read">
            <h3>READ</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If the value of the slider is 0. The content shown would be low and if the slider value is 2, the amount of content increases

Comment: It's still unclear what you were asking or trying to accomplish. Could you add a few more images showing what "content shown ... low" or "amount … content increases" means. It will make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` event to detect when the user moves the slider.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="1" class="slider" id="slide" onchange="changeContent()">
```

Then use javascript and css to modify the article. You could define classes for the article's container that are switched using javascript, effecting the container's children:

```css
.slide2 {
    display: none;
}

div.showdetail .slide2 {
    display: block;
}

div.hidedetail .slide0 {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="">
        <p> Always shown <p/>
        <p class="slide0"> Removable detail <p/>
        <p class="slide2"> Hidden till needed <p/>
        <p class="slide0"> Removable detail <p/>
        <p class="slide2"> Hidden till needed <p/>
    </div>
```

Then use javascript to add or remove classes based on the slider.